# Количество записей по о.критериям

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Мучаюсь уже как третий день на различных форумах не могу все получить верный ответ на мой вопрос: У меня есть таблица пользователей `users` и таблица `orders` так же есть страница new_order.php где есть форма отправки данных в бд, мне нужно разрешать отправлять пользователям только 1 раз форму, то есть если я заполнил форму отправил её данные в бд записались, всё, И ТОЛЬКО на следующий день я могу повторить эти действия, за каждый день можно отправить по одой записи.

Я сделал запрос:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `orders` WHERE `order_by` = '$login' AND ...???...";
```

Пояснение запроса: Я вывожу количество по следующим критериям: По тому кто заказал, переменная логин это сессия (выше в файле $login = $_SESSION['login']) ну дальше вот мне и нужно узнать сколько записей пользователь отправил за сегодня, это работа с датами и временем, помогите мне добиться желаемого результата что нужно?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если есть поле время в таблице orders (а оно должно быть) по нему и сверяйте. Добавьте условие LIKE в запрос к таблице date_order.

К примеру дата содержится в таблице в формате 2014-03-12 12-00-00 , тогда условие будет LIKE `date` '2014-03-12%'. Знак процента (%) означает что на его месте может находится любое количество любых символов. Если такой запрос вернёт не NULL значит заказ сегодня уже оформляли.

Comment: спасибо большое, попробую вашу версию отработать.

Comment: Омайгад. Нет, это все будет работать, и наверняка не порушит систему наглухо, но не нужно сравнивать даты со строками.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101436/mysql-datetime-field-with-index-get-a-range-like-vs-between-and-performance вот например потенциальная яма

Comment: я уже сделал спасибо всем кто помог, я сделал так 

$sql = "SELECT * orders WHERE `order_by`='$login' AND `order_date` = '$order_date'";
$sql_query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
$order_nums = mysqli_num_rows($sql_query);

if($order_nums < 0) { exit ('Вы уже заказывали сегодня товар') }